# Construct Rings using Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I am learning Jetpack Compose and would like to build something like this
[image]

I have tried using Box layout by stacking `CircularProgressIndicator` but requires hardcoding the circle sizes. I want the rings to be size agnostic.
How do I achieve this using Compose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to do with `Canvas`. I did this and could give you a start point to achieve what you want...

```
@Composable
fun DrawGradientCircles() {
    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(300.dp)
            .background(Color.Gray)
    ) {
        drawCircle(
            brush = Brush.sweepGradient(listOf(Color.Magenta, Color.Red)),
            radius = 300f,
            style = Stroke(90f)
        )
        drawCircle(
            brush = Brush.sweepGradient(listOf(Color.Green, Color.Yellow)),
            radius = 200f,
            style = Stroke(90f)
        )
        drawCircle(
            brush = Brush.sweepGradient(listOf(Color.Cyan, Color.Blue)),
            radius = 100f,
            style = Stroke(90f)
        )
    }
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

**EDIT:** I posted an updated version here:

https://gist.github.com/nglauber/e947dacf50155fb72408e83f6595e430

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: I see that you have provided a fixed size of 300dp in your gist. How can I provide relative size with respect to its parent view? Similar to Geometry Reader in SwiftUI ?

Comment: @MohamedWasiq the `Canvas` has a `DrawScope` which has the `size` property. Just use `size`  inside the `Canvas` if you need relative dimensions.

Comment: Ok. Thanks I will try it out.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to have a shadow on this rings ?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to accomplish it using CircularProgressIndicator

```
@Composable
fun ringView(){

var sz by remember { mutableStateOf(Size.Zero)}

    Box(
        Modifier
            .aspectRatio(1f)
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Blue)
            .onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
                sz = coordinates.size.toSize()
            }
            , contentAlignment = Alignment.Center){

        Box(Modifier.aspectRatio(1f), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center){
            Text(text = pxToDp(sz.height.toInt()).toString())
            CircularProgressIndicator(progress = 0.9F, Modifier.size(pxToDp(sz.width.toInt()).dp), strokeWidth = (pxToDp(sz.width.toInt())/15).dp,color = Color.Green)
            CircularProgressIndicator(progress = 0.9F, Modifier.size((pxToDp(sz.width.toInt())-(2*(pxToDp(sz.width.toInt())/15))).dp), strokeWidth = (pxToDp(sz.width.toInt())/15).dp, color = Color.Black )
            CircularProgressIndicator(progress = 0.9F, Modifier.size((pxToDp(sz.width.toInt())-(4*(pxToDp(sz.width.toInt())/15))).dp), strokeWidth = (pxToDp(sz.width.toInt())/15).dp, color = Color.Gray )
            CircularProgressIndicator(progress = 0.9F, Modifier.size((pxToDp(sz.width.toInt())-(6*(pxToDp(sz.width.toInt())/15))).dp), strokeWidth = (pxToDp(sz.width.toInt())/15).dp, color = Color.Cyan )
            CircularProgressIndicator(progress = 0.9F, Modifier.size((pxToDp(sz.width.toInt())-(8*(pxToDp(sz.width.toInt())/15))).dp), strokeWidth = (pxToDp(sz.width.toInt())/15).dp, color = Color.Magenta )

        }

    }

}

fun pxToDp(px: Int): Int {
return (px / Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density).toInt()
}
```

Comment: Simpler approach with predefined components