# CircularProgressIndicator with rounded corner in Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to round corners of CircularProgressIndicator using jetpack compose. But I don't see any member variables to do so.
Following is the source code, but it doesn't take Stroke as a parameter. If it can then we'll be able to create our custom Stroke with a round cap.

```
@Composable
fun CircularProgressIndicator(
    /*@FloatRange(from = 0.0, to = 1.0)*/
    progress: Float,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    color: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
    strokeWidth: Dp = ProgressIndicatorDefaults.StrokeWidth
) {
    val stroke = with(LocalDensity.current) {
        Stroke(width = strokeWidth.toPx(), cap = StrokeCap.Butt)
    }
    Canvas(
        modifier
            .progressSemantics(progress)
            .size(CircularIndicatorDiameter)
            .focusable()
    ) {
        // Start at 12 O'clock
        val startAngle = 270f
        val sweep = progress * 360f
        drawDeterminateCircularIndicator(startAngle, sweep, color, stroke)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you look at this answer? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67844459/construct-rings-using-jetpack-compose/67845350#67845350

Answer (score 9):

Starting from M2 `1.4.0-alpha04` and M3 `1.1.0-alpha04` you can use the **`strokeCap`** parameter:

```
    CircularProgressIndicator(
        //...
        strokeCap  = StrokeCap.Round,
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

cap is hardcoded in source functions. Solution I use is basically copy-pasting source functions and changing stroke cap. Also for linear indicator you need to do some additional math, so that rounded caps don't go over specified width.

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.Canvas
import androidx.compose.foundation.focusable
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.foundation.progressSemantics
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.ProgressIndicatorDefaults
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Offset
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Size
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.StrokeCap
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.DrawScope
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.Stroke
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalDensity
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.LayoutDirection
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

private val LinearIndicatorWidth = 240.dp
private val LinearIndicatorHeight = ProgressIndicatorDefaults.StrokeWidth

private val CircularIndicatorDiameter = 40.dp

@Composable
internal fun RoundedLinearProgressIndicator(
    /*@FloatRange(from = 0.0, to = 1.0)*/
    progress: Float,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    color: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
    backgroundColor: Color = color.copy(alpha = ProgressIndicatorDefaults.IndicatorBackgroundOpacity)
) {
    Canvas(
        modifier
            .progressSemantics(progress)
            .size(LinearIndicatorWidth, LinearIndicatorHeight)
            .focusable()
    ) {
        val strokeWidth = size.height
        drawRoundedLinearProgressIndicator(
            startFraction = 0f,
            endFraction = 1f,
            color = backgroundColor,
            strokeWidth = strokeWidth
        )
        drawRoundedLinearProgressIndicator(
            startFraction = 0f,
            endFraction = progress,
            color = color,
            strokeWidth = strokeWidth
        )
    }
}

@Composable
internal fun RoundedCircularProgressIndicator(
    /*@FloatRange(from = 0.0, to = 1.0)*/
    progress: Float,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    color: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
    strokeWidth: Dp = ProgressIndicatorDefaults.StrokeWidth
) {
    val stroke = with(LocalDensity.current) {
        Stroke(width = strokeWidth.toPx(), cap = StrokeCap.Round)
    }
    Canvas(
        modifier
            .progressSemantics(progress)
            .size(CircularIndicatorDiameter)
            .focusable()
    ) {
        // Start at 12 O'clock
        val startAngle = 270f
        val sweep = progress * 360f
        drawRoundedCircularIndicator(startAngle, sweep, color, stroke)
    }
}

private fun DrawScope.drawRoundedCircularIndicator(
    startAngle: Float,
    sweep: Float,
    color: Color,
    stroke: Stroke
) {
    // To draw this circle we need a rect with edges that line up with the midpoint of the stroke.
    // To do this we need to remove half the stroke width from the total diameter for both sides.
    val diameterOffset = stroke.width / 2
    val arcDimen = size.width - 2 * diameterOffset
    drawArc(
        color = color,
        startAngle = startAngle,
        sweepAngle = sweep,
        useCenter = false,
        topLeft = Offset(diameterOffset, diameterOffset),
        size = Size(arcDimen, arcDimen),
        style = stroke
    )
}

private fun DrawScope.drawRoundedLinearProgressIndicator(
    startFraction: Float,
    endFraction: Float,
    color: Color,
    strokeWidth: Float,
) {
    val cap = StrokeCap.Round
    val width = size.width
    val height = size.height
    // Start drawing from the vertical center of the stroke
    val yOffset = height / 2

    val roundedCapOffset = size.height / 2

    val isLtr = layoutDirection == LayoutDirection.Ltr
    val barStart = (if (isLtr) startFraction else 1f - endFraction) * width + if (isLtr) roundedCapOffset else -roundedCapOffset
    val barEnd = (if (isLtr) endFraction else 1f - startFraction) * width - if (isLtr) roundedCapOffset else -roundedCapOffset

    // Progress line
    drawLine(
        color = color,
        start = Offset(barStart, yOffset),
        end = Offset(barEnd, yOffset),
        strokeWidth = strokeWidth,
        cap = cap,
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I made my rounded progress like this:

```
LinearProgressIndicator(
    modifier = Modifier
    .background(Color.Transparent)
    .clip(CircleShape)
    .height(16.dp),
    progress = 1f
)
```

Answer (score 3):

just add clip to  `LinearProgressIndicator` like this:

`modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().clip(RoundedCornerShape(14.dp))`

Comment: Up voted as this kind of works. The only downside about this approach is it will not round the filled part of the bar, only the start and end of the indicator. I haven't found a way to fix this using `LinearProgressIndicator`. The alternative would be to use a completely custom appoach like done here: https://semicolonspace.com/jetpack-compose-progress-indicator-2/

Answer (score 2):

As an idea, you can just draw 2 circles above your progress

```
@Composable
fun RoundedCircularProgress(
        progress: Float,
        strokeWidth: Dp,
        progressColor: Color,
        modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Box(modifier = modifier.size(100.dp)) {
        // circle progress
        CircularProgressIndicator(
                progress = progress,
                color = progressColor,
                strokeWidth = strokeWidth,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        )
        // start circle
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .wrapContentSize(align = Alignment.TopCenter)
                .size(strokeWidth)
                .background(progressColor, CircleShape)
        )
        // end circle
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .rotate(360 * progress)
                .wrapContentSize(align = Alignment.TopCenter)
                .size(strokeWidth)
                .background(progressColor, CircleShape)
        )
    }
}
```